# How do I get all business process list through API or Web service in Primavera Unifier

Tags: primavera

I need to know all the business processes in Primavera Unifier ?
I am using the web services exposed by Primavera Unifier. But i did not find any service or method which returns the list of business processes.

Answer (score 1):

Kuls unfortunately Unifier devs don't hangout on stackoverflow. You'll have better luck in the Oracle communities for OPU or OPU LinkedIn Groups.

That said the only way to get what you want is to

1. Create a dataview pulling from sys_studio_installed (knowing which rows to pull is left as an exercise
2. At the company level or single instance shell level create a UDR from that dataview. (Don't forget to enable this udr for integration)
3. Use getUDRData method

If you want to know all BPs including incomplete/unpublished bps use sys_studio instead.